# How to insert data into pivot table in many to many relation in ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, ef-code-first-mapping

I have two models, `Movie` and `Genre`.

Movie class:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string File { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Release { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
```

Genre class:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
```

And this is the `CineDBContext` context class

```
    public virtual DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
```

I have used a code-first approach to generate the database and tables. As there has many to many relationships three tables are generated in the database `Movies`, `Genres` and `GenreMovies`.

Inside controller class:

```
private CineDBContext db = new CineDBContext();
db.Movies.Add(data); //Fills the Movies table
db.SaveChanges();

db.Genres.Add(data); //Fills the Genres table
db.SaveChanges();
```

But how can I fill the `GenreMovies` pivot table?

Comment: You don't - EF already does that for you - automagically, in the background

Comment: how will EF know which genres are for the movie?

Comment: I have already created list of genres and stored them in the database table.When admin register new movie he need to select the genres of the movie. so from view section i get the information of the movie and the array of genres. how can i store them ?

Answer (score 0):

The code should look more like this:

```
var movie = db.Movies.Add(data);

var genre = db.Genres.Add(data);

movie.Genres.Add(movie);

db.SaveChanges();
```

You'll see that the third line answers your remaining question: *how will EF know which genres are for the movie?*

But, since you used a Code-First approach then you will also need:

1. ICollections on both models specifying the many-to-many relationship (you already have this).
2. To configure the many-to-many relationship within the `OnModelCreating` of your DbContext using the Fluent API. You can read more about this [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

**For those using a Database-First approach** (using [Entity Framework Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EntityFramework6PowerToolsCommunityEdition)):

Your edmx (Entity Data Model XML) file will automagically create the relationship for you (no manual additions to the DbContext required) with a caveat:

> Entity framework supports many-to-many relationships only when the
>   joining table does NOT include any columns other than PKs of both
>   tables.
>   http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx

You'll know that your relationship is setup correctly when EFPT has put the *correct* ICollections on your models, and your edmx file doesn't show your pivot table at all -- instead, your edmx file shows a direct many-to-many relationship ( denoted by a * on both ends ) between your two tables.